# Raspberry pi Blynk LED not responding

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, blynk

I am trying to control a LED with Blynk but it doesn't seem to work. I have checked the connections and LED with a simple blinking program, everything works. I run the blynk program, the app successfully connected and I am able to print the status of the button, however, when it comes to the if statement it doesn't work.

```
from gpiozero import LED

import blynklib
    
led = LED(17)
    
BLYNK_AUTH = '' #insert your Auth Token here
    
blynk = blynklib.Blynk(BLYNK_AUTH)


while True:
    @blynk.handle_event('write V4')
    def write_virtual_pin_handler(pin, value):
        status = value[0]
        print(status)
        if status == 1:
            led.on()
            print("on")
        elif status == 0:
            led.off()
            print("off")
            
    blynk.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the `status` variable into an integer, since the list includes strings, not integers. In order to do this, change `status` to `int(status)` in the if / elif statements.

Source: [This post I found that documents this behaviour](https://community.blynk.cc/t/blynk-app-to-control-gpio-on-raspberry-pi-zero-w/45818)